# How to fix "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context" error using a leaflet map in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am sure, that there have been similar questions about this, but no solution to mine, as reactive function does not work with "RenderLeaflet" function that I need to use to make this work. I suspect there is an issue with a switch function, that I cannot get solved. Thanks a lot for your help! I am getting this error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

While I run this:

```
#

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(cartography)
library(mapproj)
library(maps)
analysis = read_csv('data/analysis.csv')
coordinates = read_csv('data/coordinates.csv')
analysis = merge(coordinates, analysis)
plomap <- function(data){
    mybins <- seq(0, 2000000,by=200000)
    mypalette <- colorBin( palette="magma", domain=analysis$total, na.color="transparent", bins=mybins)
    
    mytext <- paste(
        "total_sold: ", analysis$total_sold, "<br/>",
        "total: ", analysis$total, "<br/>",
        "store: ", analysis$`Store Name`, sep="") %>%
        lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    
    leaflet(analysis) %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        setView( lat=51, lng=19 , zoom=6) %>%
        addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Voyager") %>%
        addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat,
                         fillColor = ~mypalette(total), fillOpacity = 0.7, color="red", radius=10, stroke=FALSE,
                         label = mytext,
                         labelOptions = labelOptions( style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"), textsize = "13px", direction = "auto")
        ) %>%
        addLegend( pal=mypalette, values=~total, opacity=0.9, title = "total", position = "bottomright" )
    
}
ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("mymap"),
    p(),
    mainPanel(
        sidebarPanel(
            helpText("Choose a month to update the information displayed on the map"),
            
            selectInput("var", 
                        label = "Choose a month to display",
                        choices = c("January", "February",
                                    "March", "All"),
                        selected = "All"),
            
)
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    points <- eventReactive(input$recalc, {
        cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    analysis <- 
        switch(input$var, 
                   "January" = analysis%>%filter(month='January'),
                   "February" = analysis%>%filter(month='February'),
                   "March" = analysis%>%filter(month='March'),
                   "All" = analysis%>%select(-month)%>%summarise_all(.funs=sum))
    
    output$mymap <- 
        renderLeaflet({
        plomap(analysis())
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any use of input$... Must be wrapped with reactive() or renderLeaflet() or render... Etc otherwise it won't be watched for changes.

Comment: That's what I did, however, when I try  to do analysis <- 
        reactive(switch(input$var, 
                   "January" = analysis%>%filter(month='January'),
                   "February" = analysis%>%filter(month='February'),
                   "March" = analysis%>%filter(month='March'),
                   "All" = analysis%>%select(-month)%>%summarise_all(.funs=sum))) It just will not work for  me... There would be no error, but no results either...

Comment: Month=='january' etc.  Look at the console in Rstudio see what errors pop up there even if the shiny apps runs

Comment: I did, I made it work, but I encounter more and more problems with Rshiny

Comment: do you have a reproducable example? or example data

Comment: Here is the code. I finally got it too work. Takes some time until I figured how Rshiny thinks. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
analysismonths = merge(coordinates, analysis)
plomap <- function(data, bins = seq(0, 800000, 50000)){
  mybins <- bins
  mypalette <- colorBin( palette="magma", domain=data$total, na.color="transparent", bins=mybins)

  mytext <- paste(
    "Total Sold: ", data$total_sold, "<br/>",
    "Total Revenues: ", data$total, "<br/>",
    "Store Name: ", data$`Store Name`, sep="") %>%
    lapply(htmltools::HTML)

  leaflet(data) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    setView( lat=51, lng=19 , zoom=6) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Voyager") %>%
    addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat,
                     fillColor = ~mypalette(total), fillOpacity = 0.7, color="red", radius=10, stroke=FALSE,
                     label = mytext,
                     labelOptions = labelOptions( style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"), textsize = "13px", direction = "auto")
    ) %>%
    addLegend( pal=mypalette, values=~total, opacity=0.9, title = "Total Revenues", position = "bottomright" )

}
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  mainPanel(#(dataTableOutput('table')), 
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Choose a month to update the information displayed on the map"),

      selectInput("var",
                  label = "Select Month",
                  choices = c("January", "February",
                              "March", "All"),
                  selected = "All"),
      sliderInput('slider', 'Total Sold', value = 0, 20000, max=20000, min=0, step=50),
      sliderInput('rev', 'Total Revenues', value = 0, 2000000, max = 2000000, min = 0, step = 50000),




    ),
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput('table'))

  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <-
    renderLeaflet({
      map <- switch(input$var,
                    "January" = plomap(analysismonths%>%filter(month=='January')%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total >= input$rev)),
                    "February" = plomap(analysismonths%>%filter(month=='February')%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total >= input$rev)),
                    "March" = plomap(analysismonths%>%filter(month=='March')%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total >= input$rev)),
                    "All" = plomap(allstores <- analysis%>%select(-month)%>%group_by(`Store ID`,`Store Name`, name)%>%
                                     summarise_all(.funs = sum)%>%merge(coordinates)%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total>= input$rev), seq(0,2000000, 200000)))



    })
  output$table = renderDataTable(
    switch(input$var,
           "January" = analysismonths%>%select(-long, -lat, -pop, -name, -country.etc, - capital)%>%
             filter(month=='January')%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total >= input$rev),
           "February" = analysismonths%>%select(-long, -lat, -pop, -name, -country.etc, - capital)%>%
             filter(month=='February')%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total >= input$rev),
           "March" = analysismonths%>%select(-long, -lat,  -pop, -name, -country.etc, - capital)%>%
             filter(month=='March')%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total >= input$rev),
           "All" = allstores <- analysis[,-14]%>%select( -month )%>%group_by(`Store ID`,`Store Name`)%>%
             summarise_all(.funs = sum)%>%filter(total_sold >= input$slider, total>= input$rev)))
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```